# sitio web multilenguaje con php

Tags: php, javascript, html5

quiero que mi pagina web cambie de idioma al hacer click sobre los elementos li, esto es el codigo que llevo hasta ahora, antes cambiaba el idioma mediante un formulario el cual enviaba por method post pero esta tecnica no me gusta ya que debia hacer click en un boton de submit

```
    <?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST["lang"]))
 {
   $lang = $_POST["lang"];
   if (!empty($lang))
    {
        $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
   }
}

if (isset($_POST["lang"])) 
{
    $lang = $_POST["lang"];
```

> antes para cambiar de idioma utilizaba un formulario el cual enviaba por method POST

```
    require "lang/".$lang.".php";
}
else 
{
    require 'lang/en.php';
}
```

?>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $lang["titulo"]?></title>
</head>
<body>
     <center><ul class="lang-selector list-unstyled">
                        <li class="selected" tabindex="0" >NL</li>
                        <li  tabindex="0">EN</li>
                        <li  tabindex="0">FR</li>
                    </ul></center>
    <h1><?php echo $lang["h1"]?></h1>
    <form class="form-control">
        <label><?php echo $lang["label2"]?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="">
            <br>
        <label><?php echo $lang["ing"]?></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="send" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
    </form>
<center><span><?php echo $lang["span"]?></span>
<span><?php echo $lang["span2"]?></span>
<span><?php echo $lang["div"]?></span>
<p>
    <?php echo $lang["div2"]?>
    <?php echo $lang["div3"]?>
</p>


</center>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

//mi codigo php que cambia de lenguaje el cual va en una carpeta llamada lang

```
$lang = array(
    "titulo" => "my page in englsh",
    "h1" => "hello word", 
    "ing" => "password", 
    "label2" => "user",
    "span" => "more information",
    "span2" => "here",
    "div" => "Online privacy",
    "div2" => "Privacy",
    "div3" => "reglamento",
    "menu_lenguaje" => "EN",

);
```

//mi codigo de php que cambia de lenguaje el cual va en una carpeta llamada lang

```
<?php  

$lang = array(
    "titulo" => "mi pagina web es español",
    "h1" => "hola mundo", 
    "ing" => "contraseña", 
    "label2" => "usuario",
    "span" => "mas informacion",
    "span2" => "aqui",
    "div" => "Privacidad online",
    "div2" => "Privacidad",
    "div3" => "reglamento",
    "menu_lenguaje" => "ES",

);
```

Comment: Si ahora lo estás enviando con un enlace del tipo `index.php?lang=idioma` entonces en el primer script solo cambia `$_POST` por `$_GET` y listo!

Comment: El comentario de arriba me parece una buena opción, pero tambien creo que lo que podrias hacer es simplemente usar ciertos enlaces, haz de cuenta como los que tiene facebook para cambiar la pagina de un idioma a otro, en tu caso serian elementos li, la idea es que le anadas a estos un listener tipo click, lo prevengas y luego simplemente envies por GET los datos hacia la misma pagina, a su vez, si quieres mantener el idioma en memoria, entonces podrias usar cookies en php o el local_storage de javascript, y en caso de que si o si no quieras que se recargue la pagina, podrias usar ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario clickear en el boton de submit para enviar formularios, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, entre ellas, por medio de la escucha de otro evento generado por el usuario o el uso de ajax.

Para mantenerlo simple y no involucrarnos con ajax, que igualmente es sencillo de usar, lo mas simple que puedes hacer es que si lo que quieres es que se haga submit cuando se de click a alguno de tus elementos li para no tener que darle al boton de submit, puedes hacer que los botones li sean los que llamen al evento sumbit de tu formulario.

Es decir, aquí se encuentra tu formulario:

```
<form class="form-control">
        <label><?php echo $lang["label2"]?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="">
            <br>
        <label><?php echo $lang["ing"]?></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="send" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
</form>
```

tu formulario no tiene un id, pero para este ejemplo debería tenerlo, así que le añadiremos uno:

```
<form class="form-control" id = "formulario-control">
</form>
```

Aquí esta tu lista, la cual dices que te gustaria que cuando clickearas en cualquier li de tu lista, se cambie el idioma, es decir se envien los datos o se haga submit:

```
<ul class="lang-selector list-unstyled">
     <li class="selected" tabindex="0" >NL</li>
     <li  tabindex="0">EN</li>
     <li  tabindex="0">FR</li>
</ul>
```

Como veo que tus listas no tienen una clase definida, pero el padre de tus elementos li si, entonces se puede usar el padre para acceder a los hijos, tambien veo que estas usando jQuery, por lo que facilitara y hará mas rapidas las cosas, entonces todo esto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
//Primero obtenemos los elementos necesarios:
const formulario = $("#formulario-control");
const elementosLi = $("ul.lang-selector li");

//Ahora le añadimos un evento tipo click a cada elemento li de tu lista de lenguas:

elementosLi.on("click", ()=>{

    formulario.submit();

});
```

De esta manera, apenas des click a cualquiera de los elementos Li se hará un submit del formulario.

Es mas, en caso de que necesites manejar o cambiar algunas cosas antes de enviar al formulario lo puedes hacer, mediante el evento que provee jQuery, así podras saber por ejemplo cuál de todos tus LI fue clickeado y que contenido traia:

```
elementosLi.on("click", (event)=>{

    console.log(event.target.text());
    formulario.submit();

});
```

O hacer cualquier otro tipo de cambio que sea necesario antes de enviar el formulario, también como recomendación puedes usar `local_storage` de javascript si quieres mantener en memoria el lenguaje actual en el que se mostrara la pagina,de esta manera la proxima vez que la persona entre a la pagina, solo debes recuperar que lenguaje estaba seteado en `local_storage` y así poder mostrar la pagina en el lenguaje correcto.

Comment: Eso seria para usar con el metodo GET, ya que GET no recarga la pagina, pero si deseas usar POST, me temo que será mejor usar ajax, que realmente aprenderlo no toma mas de 1 hora o menos y es bastante sencillo de usar, ademas así no se recargaría la pagina independientemente de que metodo usases para hacer el submit, sin embargo, si lo haces con ajax, al no recargar la pagina tendrias que refrezcar tu mismo uno por uno o varios por varios, los contenidos que cambien de idioma, espero la respuesta sirva de algo, saludos!